# jquery tablesorter issue with page number

Tags: tablesorter

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 4 application using jquery.tablesorter.js, jquery.tablesorter.pager.js and jquery.tablesorter.widget.js. Now I get an issue with this tablesorter, that is, the page number is saved in the local storage.

I understand it is saved for some reasons. The problem is, for example, I last open the 3rd page of the table and leave the session, then re-open a session, it goes to the 3rd page automatically. If, for some reasons, there is not enough items for any item to go to the 3rd page, it simply shows an empty table and pager, and confuses the user.

Any idea is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
A. Zhang

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the pager to save the page & size, then set the [`savePages`](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#save-pages) option to `false`.

If you do want the page to get saved, but you only want to use session storage, then set the [`storage_useSessionStorage` widget option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#widget-storage-use-session-storage) to `true`.

Please note: the above options only work with my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/).

Comment: Thanks Mottie, I did something like that. However, this causes some other issues. Looks like a lot of functionality depends on the saving data.

Comment: What other issues specifically? I will address them more timely if you would please [open a new issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues) about the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, v2.24.6 was just released last night. Please test it out as there were updates pager page option because it wasn't working properly with `savePages` set to `false`. Sorry about that!